# Display text when hovering over image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to set up text to be hidden but when you over over an image the text shows up.

```
<img src="img/js.png" alt="Javascript" class="skill">
<p class="exp">Text goes here</p>
```

This is how my HTML is setup.

Is it possible to do this in CSS or do I have to do it in Javascript?

I'd rather not use jQuery.

Comment: I think this will have been asked on Stackoverflow before. [Here is a simple demo I made for you with just CSS](http://jsbin.com/dalega/1/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: @misterManSam I tried searching for this but I guess I didn't search hard enough. Thanks!

Comment: No worries :) I haven't found a nice match for it yet either so I left it as an answer for now. Your question could also be more clear with where you would like the text to be displayed on hover.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [the adjacent (`+`) selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors), hide the text after the image and show it when the image is hovered.

> **Adjacent sibling selectors**
>
> This is referred to as an adjacent selector. It will select only the
>   specified element that immediately follows the former specified
>   element.

In this example:

- The text is hidden with `opacity: 0`
- The text is shown on hover with `opacity: 1`
- The `transition` smoothly fades the text in and out

**Note:** The text could also be hidden with `display: none` and shown with `display: block`, but this  method cannot be transitioned.

```css
.skill + .exp {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
.skill:hover + .exp {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.placehold.it/300" alt="Javascript" class="skill">
<p class="exp">Text goes here</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply add this css code :

```
.skill {
    position:relative;
    z-index:101;
}
.skill:hover {
    z-index:99;
}
.exp{
    position : absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:20px;
    z-index:100;
}
```

fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/r3gyr9oh/

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
.exp{
  display: none;
}
.skill:hover + .exp{
  display: block;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to avoid any jquery or javascript you can use

```
  <img src="img/js.png" alt="Javascript" class="skill" title="your name">
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve? I mean you wanted to give an expression to the user if they hover over the image you want to show something like a tooltip? if that is what you want to do than that could be done by using the tile in image tag

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<img src="Your Image source" alt="Your text" width="42" height="42" title="Your text Goes here">

</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.